# Artifactory Gradle plugin throwing bizarre cast exception

Tags: groovy, gradle, artifactory

I have the following project structure (intended for a Gradle multi-project build):

```
myproj/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    fizzbuzz-client/
        build.gradle
        settings.gradle
        src/
            main/
                groovy/
                resources/
            test/
                groovy/
                resources/
    fizzbuzz-shared/
        build.gradle
        settings.gradle
        src/
            main/
                groovy/
                resources/
            test/
                groovy/
                resources/
    fizzbuzz-server/
        build.gradle
        settings.gradle
        src/
            main/
                groovy/
                resources/
            test/
                groovy/
                resources/
```

Where `myproj/build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "admin"
                password = "password"
            }
            name = "maven-main-cache"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

And where `myproj/settings.gradle` is:

```
include ':fizzbuzz-shared'
include ':fizzbuzz-client'
//include ':fizzbuzz-service'       Commented out since I have no actual code for this yet
```

And where `myproj/fizzbuzz-shared/build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

version="0.0.31"
group = "mygroup"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-snapshots"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // All my libs; omitted for brevity
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'my-snapshots'
            username = "admin"
            password = "password"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

When I navigate to the `myproj` root directory, and run `gradle build`, I get:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':fizzbuzz-client'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
    <omitted for brevity>
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownRepositoryException: Repository with name 'maven-main-cache' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.createNotFoundException(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.getByName(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.artifacts.ArtifactRepositoryContainer$getByName.call(Unknown Source)
```

The best I can reckon:

1. My project is not configured correctly (something is wrong with one of my `build.gradle` files); or
2. I'm not using the right build invocation (`gradle build`).

Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Edit: please note that in the suggested duplicate question, the problem was a result of the user having Gradle misconfigured in a CI server, and that the solution was to simply configure Gradle correctly inside the CI server. In my case, I am running Gradle locally on the command line. I therefore do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like you've got two versions of that class on your classpath

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - but how is that possible if I'm only declaring `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"` one time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gradle artifactory plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446516/gradle-artifactory-plugin)

Comment: No it is not a dupe; that user was using a CI tool; I am not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just breaking my project out into 3 small projects:

- `fizzbuzz-shared`
- `fizzbuzz-client`
- `fizzbuzz-server`

Which is a little disappointing, but is the only way I could get the Artifactory plugin to play nice with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You got two plugins running on the same time. 
One is added in your code, the other is added by the CI server (Jenkins?).

Please make sure that " Project uses the Artifactory Gradle Plugin" checkbox is selected when running the project that actually use artifactory plugin. Then we'll skip the addition of the plugin in the CI server.

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch (+1) but you are mistaken! This is code running localllyy on my machine with no CI server whatsoever! Just straight up Gradle command-line!

Comment: By "Artifactory Gradle plugin" I mean whatever plugin is pulled in when I add `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"` to my `build.gradle` file.

Comment: hm, try to get rid of `maven` or `maven-publish` plugins. You shouldn't use them both.

Comment: Thanks again @JBaruch (+1) - however I tried removing one of them at a time, and also removing both of them, and still the same error. I think your theory that there are dupe plugins is a red herring. It is important to note: if I take the `fizzbuzz-client` and move it out into its own separate project, then I am able to run `gradle build` and `gradle artifactoryPublish` with no problems whatsoever. This seems to only be happening in "multi-project mode" where a single `build.gradle` is overseeing the building of several subprojects. Thoughts?

Comment: It's some class loading related problem. Things you can try: 1. Only have a `buildscript` block in the root project's `build.gradle`. 2. Use a different Gradle version. 3. Use a different plugin version.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser (+1) - a couple of things: my `fizzbuzz-client/build.gradle` and `fizzbuzz-shared/build.gradle` are nearly identical. So I took your advice and removed both their `buildscript{}` blocks and placed it in the root project's `subproject{}` block. However I got the same error. (1) Was I correct to place `buildscript` inside `subproject`? Are there other things I should be pulling out of my nearly-identical shared/client `build.gradle` files?

Comment: And (2) To try pulling in a new version of the plugin, I assume you mean changing the version number in `classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"`, yes? Thanks again! Also, I'm a bit hesitant to change plugin/Gradle versions seeing that this works perfectly if I place the shared and client subprojects in their own respective root projects and build them separately.

Comment: You shouldn't have `subprojects { buildscript { ... } }` in the root `build.gradle`, but `buildscript { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser (+1 again) - please see my update; I moved `buildscript` up to the same leevel as `subprojects`, and now am getting a new error that may shine light on the problem. It is complaining that the `fizzbuzz-client` can't find a `maven-main-cache` repo...but why would the error just be for `fizzbuzz-client` and not `fizzbuzz-shared`? Thanks again!

Comment: Get rid of all lines of the form `add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")`. It would be strange if the production code would need dependencies located in a `plugins-release` repository.